# Django CMS Multisite User Permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-cms

Im starting a project using Django CMS that has multiple sites being controlled from one instance of Django CMS. I have found the documentation for [User Permissions and Group Permissions](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/topics/permissions.html) but didn't see anything by default about permissions depending on which site the user is on.

I want to be able to give user a group and have them only be able to login to a specific site(s). Im sure this is going to be possible by requesting the current `SITE_ID` but I just wanted to see if anyone could point me in the right direction of a plugin or middleware that might let me do this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sam,
Did find any solution? I need exactly same feature.

Comment: Hi @NareshWalia I haven't found a solution online yet, once I start working on the project I suspect it will need something bespoke and once I find a solution I will post it here if someone else doesn't first.